# Failed to restart gnome-remote-desktop.service: Unit dbus.socket not found

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, dbus

Getting below error when I try to restart/start remote desktop on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and 22.04.3 also.

systemctl --user status gnome-remote-desktop.service
○ gnome-remote-desktop.service - GNOME Remote Desktop
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-remote-desktop.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

systemctl --user restart gnome-remote-desktop.service
Failed to restart gnome-remote-desktop.service: Unit dbus.socket not found.

The sharing settings are enabled as per page https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-control/

Can someone please help in checking this what might be the issue here , the OS is also newly installed. Also it is observed that Sharing remote desktop settings get disabled automatically after enabling when we go to back page